# Finding the sum based on value in collection using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I am basically trying to sum the records based on criteria and then set the value long or short. In the code below I need to sum records based on

```
if sum(Derivative) = 0, and if sum(Collateral) >=0 then NSFRDirection = 'Extra collateral Out',
   if sum(Collateral) <0 then 'Extra collateral In'
```

As you can see in the code below positions is of the type NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition  defined below.  How do I sum based on the value of FsaProduct. I am getting compile time error
but I am written a pseduo of what i want to achieve. Please see the getdirections method

Position class

```
public class NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition
{
    public decimal RegUsdAmount { get; set; }
    public string CifId { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string FsaProduct { get; set; }
}
```

AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty class

```
public class AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty : AldbRunDataEntity
 {
    public string CounterpartyCifId { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }

    public AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty(){}
    public AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty(string counterpartyCifId, string direction, AlEtlRunContext runContext)
        :base(runContext)
    {
        CounterpartyCifId = counterpartyCifId;
        Direction = direction;
    }
 }
```

Main method

```
public IList<AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty> CreateLongShortPositions(AlEtlRunContext runContext)
    {
        var positions = storedProcsRepository.GetLongShortNSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition(runContext);

        var counterpartyPositions = from p in positions
            select new NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition { CifId = p.CifId,  RegUsdAmount = p.RegUsdAmount}
            into adjusted
            group adjusted by adjusted.CifId
            into grp
            select new AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty(grp.Key, GetDirection(grp),
                 runContext);

        return counterpartyPositions.ToList();
    }
```

Method that returns the direction

```
 private static string GetDirection(IEnumerable<NSFRDerivativeCounterpartyPosition> positions)
    {
        if (!positions.Any())
        {
            return LongShortIsinType.None;
        }

        return (positions.Sum(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account") = 0  
                              &&  positions.Sum(x => x.FsaProduct != "Cash Account") = 0  ? 'Extra collateral Out' : 'Extra collateral In';

    }
```

records in the position collection looks like

[image]

Comment: I *have* to ask. What is a `AldbLongShortNSFRDerivativeCollateralCounterparty`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your domain, but it looks like you want something like

```
positions.Where(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account").Sum(x => x.RegUsdAmount) == 0
```

rather than

```
positions.Sum(x => x.FsaProduct == "Cash Account") = 0
```

`=` is the symbol that sets the value of something, `==` is the symbol for "equals". And [LINQ's `Sum` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8) takes a function that selects the value to sum.